# Rails 2.3 migration issue with helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I'm migrating a plugin of mine that uses engines plugin.
In my plugin there is a helper which is not being recognized by rails.

Does anyone knows any issue related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I must include my helpers manually, like:

```
ActionView::Base.send :include, ResourcesHelper
```

in init.rb file.